# Build Pipeline for dot net core service fails with error 401 (Unauthorized) when provided globalPackagesFolder in nuget.config

Tags: azure, azure-devops, nuget, asp.net-core-webapi, nuget-package-restore

Facing a strange issue in build pipeline in ADO for **dot net core service**.

I am trying to set a path for the packages being referred in nuget.config file. Below is nuget.config file.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <config>
    <add key="repositorypath" value="..\..\Packages" />
     <!--Affects projects using PackageReference only--> 
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="..\..\Packages" />
    <add key="dependencyversion" value="HighestMinor" />
  </config>
  <solution>
    <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
  </solution>
  <packageRestore>
    <!-- Allow NuGet to download missing packages -->
    <add key="enabled" value="True" />
    <!-- Automatically check for missing packages during build in Visual Studio -->
    <add key="automatic" value="True" />
  </packageRestore>
  <activePackageSource>
    <add key="All" value="(Aggregate source)" />
  </activePackageSource>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="NuGet Server" value="my private feed" />
    <add key="NuGet" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>
  <disabledPackageSources />
</configuration>
```

After adding below line getting 401 Unauthorised.

```
<add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="..\..\Packages" />
```

**Exception**

```
Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'myfeed/nuget/v3/flat2/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection/index.json'.
  Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
  Restore failed in 8.09 sec for /home/vsts/work/1/s/Service/Test/myproject.Tests/myproject.Tests.csproj.
```

Below are tasks in build pipeline

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    #command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: 'Service/myservice.sln'
    feedsToUse: config
    nugetConfigPath: 'Service/.nuget/nuget.config'
    externalFeedCredentials: 'MyPackages'

- script: dotnet build "Service/myservice.sln" --configuration $(buildConfiguration) -p:langversion=latest
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Build Pipeline for dot net core service fails with error 401 (Unauthorized) when provided globalPackagesFolder in nuget.config

According to the error message:

> ```
> Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsync' for source 'myfeed/nuget/v3/xxx'.
>   Response status code does not indicate success: 401 (Unauthorized).
> ```

We could to know it is trying to access your private nuget feed and get this 401 (Unauthorized) error. It seems you did not provide certification information in the `nuget.config` file.

To resolve this issue, please try to add the certification information in your `nuget.config` as following:

```
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <NuGet Server>
      <add key="Username" value="xxxxx" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="Password/PAT" />
    </NuGet Server>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
```

Check [this](https://intercom.help/appcenter/en/articles/2216043-restore-private-azuredevops-package-management-feeds-using-pat) thread for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @Leo for the response. I have provided externalFeedCredentials in pipeline. Pipeline build fails only when I add 
    <add key="globalPackagesFolder" value="..\..\Packages" /> to nuget.config. on local solution builds, successfully.

Comment: @manojmore, Sorry for the later reply. I was invited to other threads until now. Have you tried add a arguments with dotnet build `--no-restore`. Since you have using nuget restore the solution, dotent build task will implicitly restore the nuget package, but it will not using your externalFeedCredentials . Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build